# How to make image not snap to cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make an image follow the mouse. It works, but the problem I'm having is that upon refresh/first movement, the image will appear at the top left and snap to the mouse position. How do I get rid of that process and just have the image appear from under the mouse?

```js
const mouse_trail = document.getElementById('mouse_trail');

window.onmousemove = e => {
  mouse_trail.style.opacity = 1;

  const x = e.clientX - mouse_trail.offsetWidth / 2,
    y = e.clientY - mouse_trail.offsetHeight / 2;

  const keyframes = {
    transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
  }

  mouse_trail.animate(keyframes, {
    duration: 800,
    fill: 'forwards'
  });
}
```

```css
#mouse_trail {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

#mouse_trail img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  animation: rotate 2.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse_trail">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want but your clientX and clientY are MouseEvent so your image moves with mouse movement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a flag to check if this is the first time you are moving the element, and if so, animate it to that target position with a duration of 0.

```js
const mouse_trail = document.getElementById('mouse_trail');
let didMoveYet = false;

window.onmousemove = e => {
  mouse_trail.style.opacity = 1;

  const x = e.clientX - mouse_trail.offsetWidth / 2,
    y = e.clientY - mouse_trail.offsetHeight / 2;

  const keyframes = {
    transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
  }

  if (!didMoveYet) {
    didMoveYet = true;
    mouse_trail.animate(keyframes, {
    duration: 0,
    fill: 'forwards'
  });
  }
  
  mouse_trail.animate(keyframes, {
    duration: 800,
    fill: 'forwards'
  });
}
```

```css
#mouse_trail {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

#mouse_trail img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  animation: rotate 2.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse_trail">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: that's sick, thanks

Comment: edit: any idea how to get it to where multiple of the same image are following the cursor + it has a fading effect? Sort of like this codepen: https://codepen.io/jeffersonlam/pen/NqrWeL

Answer (score 0):

We might hack our way into a nicer behavior by rendering the image outside of the view

```
#mouse_trail {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}
```

even if the image snaps to the cursor, it will snap from outside of what the user can see.

*feel free to change top and left params to make the image disapear outisde of view*